# Constant Wavefunction: Sketch and normalize

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

The wavefunction of a particle in a box of length $a$ for t = 0 is constant within the range $$\left(\frac{ a}{2}\right) - ϵ$$ and $$\left(\frac{ a}{2}\right) + ϵ$$ and 0 otherwise.

Sketch and normalize this wavefunction.

Where is this particle likely to be found at t = 0?

My question is: is it possible to have a constant wavefunction? The question gives that the wavefunction is constant, but that would mean if you sketch it, it's a horizontal line, and I thought the wave function is always a sinusoidal wave? If it is constant does it still have the formula $$\left(A\sin\frac{ nπx}{a}\right) ?$$
Also if it is constant, isn't it equally likely to be found anywhere within the bounded region at t=0?

Answer (score 1):

A wavefunction can have basically any shape you like — provided it's bounded and normalizable. The sinusoid you suggest is an eigenfunction of your box (i.e. the wavefunction of a state with definite energy), while the piecewise-constant wavefunction given in the problem is just an initial condition for time-dependent Schrödinger's equation.

Comment: When it says that the wavefunction is constant though, does it mean that it is constant in space; so that it's shape doesn't change as the wavefunction time evolves?

Comment: @Ella depends on the Hamiltonian. With certain Hamiltonians such a wavefunction may be constant in time. But in general such discontinuous wavefunction will immediately spread out in space. See e.g. an animation in [this question at Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934743/) for approximation of how edge of such wavefunction evolves in constant potential.